# Is my ISP blocking the ports 5050 and 6060

Tags: port, tcpip, blocking, isp

I want to find out whether or not my ISP is blocking the ports 5050 and 6060 which I need for my voip software on my iPhone. I'm using a 3G stick with a prepaid plan, and I'm using the internet sharing option on my mac to get internet on my iPhone through my macbook's wifi.

And if not, I'm looking for a way to get my voip software working.

Answer (score 1):

Use [this site](http://www.canyouseeme.org/). Enter the port number you want to check and click `Check`.

Comment: If you're not running a service on that port, it also says the isp is blocking the port.. However, I quickly made a java application to listen on port 5050 and 6060 and it seems like the isp isn't blocking the ports...

Comment: Hm, that's odd. It doesn't say anywhere on the site that a service needs to be running. So your java app solved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal. Try the following commands, replacing the portion in brackets with the server name or IP of your VoIP server:

```
telnet [voip server name or ip] 5050
telnet [voip server name or ip] 6000
```

If it is blocked, telnet will not connect (you'll receive an error about this immediately or after a brief moment).